# How to understand if my Microsoft Office 2011 is licensed?

Tags: microsoft-word

i am using MS Word 2011 for Mac and I need to understand if it is officially licensed or cracked, is that possible?

Comment: Have you put any effort so far into researching this? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Thanks for reply,  when i checked about word section there is product id and informations like it is registered version, and i tried to find somethings in microsoft office pages but i have some doubts about if it is licensed.

Comment: I need to figure this out in short time because it is company's mac and we have to use licensed products, so i thought it will be helpful if i ll ask some help here.

Comment: You can simply call Microsoft and ask them. They will ask you information like the product ID and key, and usually they'll tell you right there whether it is legit or not.

Comment: What makes you suspect the product is not licensed?  Does the product id match the companies software purchase history?  Unlicensed software is simply not just installed, and if it is, then your user permissions should be looked at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually if a product is marked as registered and/or genuine, then it is. There are exceptions, as there is software out there that can bypass activation illegally, but if it's marked as genuine and there is no evidence of piracy you should be okay.

The only sure-fire way of knowing you are not using pirated licenses is to call Microsoft. They will ask for the product name and product key that you are using. If you don't know what your product key is, there are plenty of product key finders (like [MacProductKeyfinder](http://mac-product-key-finder.com/)) available that can find what ones are installed on your system.

Microsoft will be able to confirm whether or not the product key you are using is genuine.

---

**Note**:

There are certain licensing requirements for documentation that proves a business or user has legally purchased a copy of Microsoft software. That is always described in the [EULA](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/legal/intellectualproperty/UseTerms/default.aspx), and that document takes precedence over anything you've read from me above.